# SQL query for custom taxonomy slugs

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wpdb, sql

I need an array of custom taxonomy slugs.
In the front-end, I get it using `get_terms():`

```
$tax_slugs = get_terms( 'course', array( 'fields' => 'slugs', 'parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0 ));
print_r($tax_slugs);

result: Array ( [0] => breakfast [1] => lunch [2] => dinner [3] => dessert )
```

In the admin, the "Invalid Taxonomy" error will be raised by the function `get_terms()` because I've registered my taxonomy on the `init` action hook.

I need a function with SQL query and prepare method, to get an array of custom taxonomy slugs, like the one obtained with `get_terms()`

Comment: Is there a reason you need them before the `init` hook?

Comment: I need it to create a theme option to sort the posts by taxonomy.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't do it after the init hook. Where you creating theme options?

Comment: I'm using Redux Framework to create theme options and I always get "Invalid Taxonomy" error in the backend, except with SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;

$slugs = $wpdb->get_col(
    "SELECT
        slug
    FROM
        $wpdb->terms
    LEFT JOIN
        $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
            $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id
    WHERE
        $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'course'"
);
```

That will return an array of strings representing the taxonomy term slugs for terms in the `course` taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you Jacob!
Is it possible to select only parent terms and exclude empty ones?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, you just need to modify the query to look at those columns. Term parents and counts are in the `term_taxonomy` table, so you'd add `AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.parent = 0 AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count > 0` to the `WHERE` clause.